# Apache Flink: Failed to resolve JobManager in Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

Using Eclipse IDE to submit Flink to Yarn single node cluster I getting :
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Failed to resolve JobManager

The Jar copy a file from one location in Hdfs to another and works file 
where executed locally on cluster e.g 
sudo bin/flink run -c Test ./examples/MyJar.jar hdfs://localhost:9000/flink/in.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/flink/out.txt

code:

```Java
ExecutionEnvironment envRemote =  
ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment
(FLINK_SERVER_URL,FLINK PORT,PATH_JAR_ON_CLIENT);

DataSet<String> data = 
envRemote.readTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/flink/in.txt");

data.writeAsText("hdfs://localhost:9000/flink/out.txt");
envRemote.execute();
```

Comment: Which values did you use for FLINK_SERVER_URL and FLINK_PORT?
Every time you deploy Flink on YARN, the host and port change, because the JobManager is started on a different YARN container.